# Nami getUtxos() method not as good as Eternl's

Tags: nami-wallet, eternl, lightwallet

I am building a transaction that includes more than one asset in the output of a transaction. After I set up the output and try to build a transaction using getUtxos(outputValue) I get undefined from Nami while Eternal works fine using the same code.

outputValue contains both ada and several other assets.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation for getUtxos():

> `cardano.getUtxos(amount, paginate)`
>
> ```
> cardano.getUtxos(amount?: Value, paginate?: {page: number, limit: number}) : [TransactionUnspentOutput]
> ```
>
> TransactionUnspentOutput is a hex encoded bytes string.

[image]

Now just deserialize the hex-encoded cbor string, for example in Python using the `cbor2` package:

```
import cbor2   
                                                                                                                                             
utxos = cbor2.loads(bytes.fromhex("YOUR_CBOR_STRING"))
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
for k, v in utxos[1][1][1].items():
    print(k.hex(), v)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am aware of how to use getUtxos() method. My issue is that Nami wallet returns "undefined" while Eternl returns a correct list of utxos when I use the same code with both.

Looks like Nam's is less efficient in selecting utxos to fulfill the outputs of a transaction. Or is there a different method in Nami other than the default getUtxos()?

For example, try and build a tx where you need 3 or 4 NFTs sent from wallet along with some ADA. You will notice that Eternl has no issue, where Nami tried to include all utxos or none.